# Who was Uttamaujas in Mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas

On the last night of the war after Duryodhana's defeat, Ashwatthama  attacked the Pandava camp and strangled Dhrishtadyumna to death in his sleep, he killed Shikhandi and Uttamaujas , He killed Draupadi's five sons, the Upapandavas, while they were sleeping, believing them to be the five Pandava brothers and many other prominent warriors of the Pandava army.

So who was Uttamaujas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the source : [Uttamaujas - A Panchala Prince](http://www.apamnapat.com/entities/Uttamaujas.html)

> Uttamaujas was a Panchala prince, a great warrior, who fought on the Pandava side in the great Kurukshetra war. Along with his comrade Yudhamanyu, he was assigned the task of protecting the chariot wheels of Arjuna, which duty he discharged admirably. Although he took part in a few single combats in the war, for the most part, he is mentioned as accompanying and guarding Arjuna.
>
> Having survived the eighteen day war, he was killed in his sleep by Drona's son Ashwatthama during the despicable night-raid on the Pandava camp.